# How do I convert/truncate any big number to its first 3 digit in C?

Tags: c

eg : 99999999 to 999,
1382953292 to 138,
12115454.54545 to 121,
9856.12154848 to 985,

Basically, I want to truncate a big number to its first 3 digit without rounding it up.

The input is in 'double'.

Comment: Convert  to string and take 3 first characters

Comment: tricky, that without rounding it up...

Comment: You just need to know how to convert a double to a string, how to split a string at a given index, and how to convert a string to a number. All those parts should be very easy on their own, you just have to combine them.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: So that the number `12.34546` becomes the string `"12."`, and `0.01999999` becomes `"0.0"`?

Comment: I think the question needs more information - e.g. if you care about performance, if you care about small numbers (in the range -100.0 to +100.0), and if you care about precision (e.g. any multiplication or division causing precision loss and wrong results).

Comment: @Brendan the range is from 0 to 10^15.

Comment: @DeepPatel Given " 0 to 10^15", what should be the result of `0.0000000000100`?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I ...truncate any ... number to its first 3 digits?

It is easy to get the wrong answer with edges cases.  Testing with `double` values near powers of ten, and just above/below would help shake out weaker solutions.

---

Converting to a string risks rounding in the textual output, unless the precision used is great enough to prevent rounding of the 3 MS digits.  I recommend to start with `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG`.

With values >= 1.0, no problem

```
char buf[1+1+1+DBL_DECIMAL_DIG+1+1+6      +1];
//       - d . ddzzzzzzzzzzzzz e - eeeeee \0

snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%+.*e", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, some_double);
// Set the least significant digits to 0
memset(buf + 5, DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 3, '0');
printf("%s %.*e\n", buf, DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, atof(buf));
// To just a 3 digit int
buf[2] = buf[3]; buf[3] = buf[4]; buf[4] = '\0';
printf("%s %d\n", buf, atoi(buf));
```

For various values < 1.0 and near a power of ten, some issues may remain.  Will look into that more later.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of ways to do it. Some of them would be:

- Convert the number to a string, take the first 3 characters and then convert it back to a number.
- Divide the number by 10 and capture the result as an integer. Repeat the previous step in a loop until the number becomes less than 1000.

Answer (score 0):

For a range from 0 to 10^15; I'd be tempted to start by finding a multiplier that will convert the number to the range 100 to 999. For example (for a smaller range, untested, incomplete):

```
    if(number >= 10000000000.0) {
        multiplier = 100000000.0;
    } else if(number >= 1000000000.0) {
        multiplier = 10000000.0;
    } else if(number >= 100000000.0) {
        multiplier = 1000000.0;
    } else if(number >= 10000000.0) {
        multiplier = 100000.0;
    } else if(number >= 1000000.0) {
        multiplier = 10000.0;
    } else if(number >= 100000.0) {
        multiplier = 1000.0;
    } else if(number >= 10000.0) {
        multiplier = 100.0;
    } else if(number >= 1000.0) {
        multiplier = 10.0;
    } else ....
```

Once the multiplier is found, you'd use it to convert the number into an integer in the range 100 to 999, like this:

```
unsigned int result = number * multiplier;
```

Then you'd print the integer:

```
printf("%u\n", result);
```

For performance; finding the multiplier can be done with a kind of binary search to reduce the number of branches executed. For example (for a smaller range, untested, incomplete):

```
    if(number >= 10000.0) {
        if(number >= 1000000.0) {
            if(number >= 10000000.0) {
                multiplier = 100000.0;
            } else {
                multiplier = 10000.0;
            }
        } else {
            if(number >= 100000.0) {
                multiplier = 1000.0;
            } else {
                multiplier = 100.0;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if(number >= 100.0) {
            if(number >= 1000.0) {
                multiplier = 10.0;
            } else {
                multiplier = 1.0;
            }
        } else {
            if(number >= 10.0) {
                multiplier = ?????
            } else {
                multiplier = ?????
            }
        }
    }
```

For numbers that are in the range 0 to 99, you'll have to decide if leading zeros should, or shouldn't, be considered part of "first 3 digits". For example, for the value `0.000000123` you might say that the first 3 digits are `000` (leading zeros are included), and you might say that the first 3 digits are `123` (leading zeros are excluded). This will determine how you choose the multiplier for these numbers and if you have more tests (e.g. `if(number >= 0.000000001)`, etc).

You will also have to make a similar decision for trailing zeros. For example, for the number `5.0` you could say that the result is `500` (trailing zeros included to ensure you always have 3 digits) or you could say that the result is `5` (trailing zeros excluded because there was only one digit).

Depending on these decisions; the code to handle numbers in the range 0 to 99 may become much more complicated.

**About Precision**

Floating point formats are notoriously bad if you want "guaranteed correct" results due to precision loss that can be introduced by any operation. My approach minimizes the potential for precision loss by ensuring there are only 2 places it can come from (rounding of the multiplier, and the single multiplication); but this does not guarantee the result is correct (e.g. for a large number like `19999999999999.999`, the result might be `200`).

If you need "guaranteed correct" it becomes extremely difficult. For example, you might be tempted to do an "`if(result * multiplier > value)`" test in the hope of catching (then fixing) wrong results; but this check would also have potential for precision loss and may do the wrong thing.

In general, my advice is that if you need correct results you shouldn't be using floating point formats - e.g. that it's easier to use "big integers" so that you can avoid precision loss.

Answer (score 0):

This function converts `double` to three number integer it will not work for `0.0` and some negative numbers.

It takes 3 numbers ignoring zeroes for example: `firstThree(-0.0000000001234)` will return `123`, `firstThree(-0.0000000001)` will return `100`

Maybe I do not understand the idea so be free do DV me as many times as you wish.

```
int firstThree(double x)
{
    double lg;
    int ndigits;

    if(x < 0) x *= -1;

    lg = log10(x);
    ndigits = lg > 0 ? lg : round(lg);

    if(ndigits > 0) 
    {
        x /= pow(10, ndigits - 2);
    }
    else 
    {
        if(!ndigits)
        {
            if(x >= 1.0)
            {
                x *= 100.0;
            }
            else
            {
                x *= 1000.0;
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            x *= pow(10, abs(ndigits)); 
            x *= 100;
        }
    }

    return x;
}
int main(void)
{
    printf("%.20f\n", DBL_MAX);
    printf("%d\n", firstThree(DBL_MAX));
    printf("%.900f\n", DBL_MIN);
    printf("%d\n", firstThree(DBL_MIN));

    printf("%.30f\n", 99999999999999.0);
    printf("%d\n", firstThree(99999999999999.0));

    printf("%.10000f\n", 9.999999999999999);
    printf("%d\n", firstThree(9.999999999999999));

    printf("%.10000f\n", 0.9999999999999999);
    printf("%d\n", firstThree(0.9999999999999999));

    printf("%.10000f\n", 0.1);
    printf("%d\n", firstThree(0.1));
    printf("%.1000f\n", 0.00000001999);
    printf("%d\n", firstThree(0.00000001999));
}
```